# What is the easiest way to install 32 bit java on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I need to install 32 bit JAVA to get SOS JobScheduler to work however I'm not sure what would be the right command for it. sudo apt-get install default-jre  would install the 64 bit version...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre:i386
```

Explanation:

In Debian (and Ubuntu, which is based on it), you can install the same package for multiple architectures side by side - this is called "multiarch". When installing a package, the part after the colon indicates the architecture (in this case i386, i.e. 32bit). Without the colon part, you get the default architecture. See the [MultiarchHOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work as expected. After the installation I ran the following command: java -version
and I got this: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: @user1029829: That means you already have the 64bit JRE installed. You'll probably need to invoke the 32bit JRE with full path name.

Comment: Ok, I tried this: "sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\* icedtea-\* icedtea6-\*" Then "java -version" returned:  "/usr/bin/java: No such file or directory" then I did: "sudo apt-get install default-jre:i386" and afterwords: "java -version" returned 64bit version again :(

Comment: @user1029829: Strange, this should work, AFAIK. Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/110852/can-i-install-a-32-bit-java-in-addition-to-a-64-bit-version , maybe this helps.

Comment: It's installed into: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-i386/bin - just add it to PATH in script and you're done.
It makes sense to not set it as default JVM, because for most usages 64-bit JVM is better, 32-bit JVM makes sense only when a legacy app uses a 32-bit .so lib.